# How to search for files in much faster way than windows search using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I used OS.walk() and it was very slow, then I tried scandir.walk() and the speed is the same as windows search. 
I found there is a package called faster_than_walk, but I'm unable to install the package as it shows the following error.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\regiment\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Regiment\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e640spf_\faster-than
>   -walk\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Regiment\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e640spf_\faster-than-walk\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Regiment\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sndrd71q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: C:\Users\Regiment\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e640spf_\faster-than-walk\

---

This is the code I'm using to search files now.

```
import fnmatch

import os

import shutil

import getpass

import scandir

usern = getpass.getuser()

rootPath = input('Please enter the location: ')

pattern = input('Please enter resto ID: ')

pattern = pattern + "_*"

for root, dirs, files in scandir.walk(rootPath):

    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):

        print(os.path.join(root, filename))

        newPath = shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), 'C:\\Users\\'+ usern +'\\Desktop\\fetchy')

print('Done')
```

---

Please help me in increasing the search speed. Python should search for a file in all the subfolders.

Comment: Ignoring the question itself, what makes you think it's possible to have  Python code run faster than OS code, which is (hopefully) written in a (much?) lower-level and more optimized?

Comment: @DeepSpace thing is that he's using Windows. So yes, he probably can make a text research faster than windows search do as it involves many "useless" display things etc than may slow down the search speed.

Comment: OS.walk speed is 225.98 where faster_than_walk speed is 70.0. https://pypi.org/project/faster-than-walk/

Comment: @Flo I should have known better and expect  that an anti-windows comment is coming my way. Still, "even" Windows code will be faster than a Python code that needs to iterate and open/close each file

Comment: If you scan the whole folder and deal with a search in an array of string, that may be very fast. Could you tell us what you want as an output? Just a boolean telling the file exists or a list of filenames (or path) that contains the string you typed?

Comment: @Flo, my python code is asking for the parent folder location and the first few letters of resto ID. I want python to check if there is any file that starts with those letters, then moves that file to another location.

Comment: @Flo and yet the premise of the question that some Python code can be faster than Windows' ""search-by-filename"", which sounds absurd. But I'd love to be shown otherwise. It might sound like I'm nitpicking, but if the premise of the question is wrong maybe OP can just use built-in tools instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Gokkul What I would do is to scan the whole folder to build an array of string (=array of filepath or filename, or both in a dict ?) and do the search on the string array. This way you iterate only once on the whole folder/files. And all you just do is to search in an array of string (which should be fast...). Once a filename match, you get its path and voilà.

Comment: @Flo I can't prove that no python program can be faster than windows search. Can you prove that there is at least one python program faster than windows search? The entire premise of the question assumes that the answer to that question is "yes"

Comment: @Flo The funny thing is that OP wants a program faster than Windows search, but they provide a benchmark that was performed on Arch Linux...

Comment: Yeah but as you may know windows search does not search only by filenames, but also by file content (and/or metadata), which can slow down the search on a very big folder (by big i mean a lot of files) + the fact it has to update the GUI. While the OP only wants to search by filename.
I know that you can configure windows search to only check filenames, but this is not default behaviour..